# Invalid characters found.[Code 18] from validator json in php

Tags: php, json, codeigniter-3

i have this json, in this case i am check a validation of my url and i see this error in this line

```
"Titulo":" 
            Incendio forestal más mortífero de la historia de Portugal: ¿Cómo se enfrentó en comparación con Chile?",
"Bajada":"
 07:03 |  Más de 60 personas murieron este fin de semana en localidad de 
 Pedrogao Grande producto del fuego, muchos de ellos mientras intentaban 
 escapar a través de la carretera. 
        ",
```

the message is Invalid characters found.[Code 18] , i try eregi_replace, trim and addslashe but doesn´t work, the data json is of a db and the info is from scraping, thanks and you have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid because it contains line breaks.  Line breaks in a JSON String must be escaped to `\n`.

This is valid JSON:

```
{
    "Titulo": " Incendio forestal más mortífero de la historia de Portugal: ¿Cómo se enfrentó en comparación con Chile ? ",
    "Bajada": "07: 03 | Más de 60 personas murieron este fin de semana en localidad de Pedrogao Grande producto del fuego, muchos de ellos mientras intentaban escapar a través de la carretera."
}
```

If your text should be on multi-line, insert `\n`where necessary. For example:

```
{
    "Titulo": " Incendio forestal más mortífero de la historia de \n ¿Cómo se enfrentó en comparación con Chile?",
    "Bajada": " 07:03 |  Más de 60 personas murieron este fin de semana en localidad de \n Pedrogao Grande producto del fuego, \n muchos de ellos mientras intentaban \n escapar a través de la carretera."
}
```

You can use this online tool to test whether your JSON is valid:

https://jsonlint.com/